# QTcpSocket and TCP padding

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, tcp, qtcpsocket

Good day.

I am sending a custom protocol for logging via TCP which looks like this:

```
Timestamp (uint32_t -> 4 bytes)
Length of message (uint8_t -> 1 byte)
Message (char -> Length of message)
```

The Timestamp is converted to `BigEndian` for the transport and everything goes out correctly, except for one little detail: Padding

The Timestamp is sent on its own, however instead of just sending the timestamp (4 bytes) my application (using BSD sockets under Ubuntu) automatically appends two bytes of padding to the message.

Wireshark recognizes this correctly and marks the two extraneous bytes as padding, however the QTcpSocket (Qt 5.8, mingw 5.3.0) apparently assumes that the two extra bytes are actually payload, which obviously messes up my protocol.

Is there any way for me to 'teach' QTcpSocket to ignore the padding (like it should) or any way to get rid of the padding?

I'd like to avoid to do the whole 'create a sufficiently large buffer and preassemble the entire packet in it so it will be sent out in one go'-method if possible.

Thank you very much.

Because it was asked, the code used to send the data is:

```
return 
    C->sendInt(entry.TS)        &&
    C->send(&entry.LogLen, 1)   &&
    C->send(&entry.LogMsg, entry.LogLen);
```

where sendInt is declared as (`Src` being the parameter):

```
Src = htonl(Src);
return send(&Src, 4);
```

where 'send' is declared as (`Source` and `Len` being the parameters):

```
char *Src = (char *)Source;
while(Len) {
    int BCount = ::send(Sock, Src, Len, 0);
    if(BCount < 1) return false;
    Src     += BCount;
    Len     -= BCount;
}
return true;
```

::send is the standard BSD send function.

Reading is done via `QTcpSocket`:

```
uint32_t timestamp;
if (Sock.read((char *)&timestamp, sizeof(timestamp)) > 0)
{
    uint8_t logLen;
    char message[256];            
    if (Sock.read((char *)&logLen, sizeof(logLen)) > 0  &&
        logLen > 0                                      &&
        Sock.read(message, logLen) == logLen
    ) addToLog(qFromBigEndian(timestamp), message);
}
```

`Sock` is the `QTcpSocket` instance, already connected to the host and `addToLog` is the processing function.

Also to be noted, the sending side needs to run on an embedded system, using `QTcpServer` is therefor not an option.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code being used to encode/send the data.  Using TCP there shouldn't be any padding.

Comment: You could be hitting the minimum Ethernet Frame size which is 64 byte including the Checksum, which you will not see in Wireshark. Since Wireshark is recognizing this, I guess that is what it is and padding is added. On the other hand, this should not propagate to user space and padding should be displayed in the Ethernet section.

Comment: @RolfWinter That may well be possible, yes.
And Wireshark does recognize it and does place it in the correct section, QTcpSocket is the one messing it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your read logic appears to be incorrect.  You have...

```
uint32_t timestamp;
if (Sock.read((char *)&timestamp, sizeof(timestamp)) > 0)
{
    uint8_t logLen;
    char message[256];            
    if (Sock.read((char *)&logLen, sizeof(logLen)) > 0  &&
        logLen > 0                                      &&
        Sock.read(message, logLen) == logLen
    ) addToLog(qFromBigEndian(timestamp), message);
}
```

From the documentation for [`QTcpSocket::read(data, MaxSize)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#read) it...

> Reads at most maxSize bytes from the device into data, and returns the
>   number of bytes read

What if one of your calls to `Sock.read` reads partial data?  You essentially discard that data rather than buffering it for reuse next time.

Assuming you have a suitably scoped `QByteArray`...

```
QByteArray data;
```

your reading logic should be more along the lines of...

```
/*
 * Append all available data to `data'.
 */
data.append(Sock.readAll());

/*
 * Now repeatedly read/trim messages from data until
 * we have no further complete messages.
 */
while (contains_complete_log_message(data)) {
  auto message = read_message_from_data(data);
  data = data.right(data.size() - message.size());
}

/*
 * At this point `data' may be non-empty but doesn't
 * contain enough data for a complete message.
 */
```

Comment: Yes, I think I've realized the error myself by now.
I am too used to the BSD way of things I believe.
Cause those would block until sufficient data is available.
I feel so silly right now.

Answer (score 1):

If the length of the padding is always fixed then just add `socket->read(2);` to ignore the 2 bytes.

On the other hand it might be just the tip of the iceberg. What are you using to read and write?

Comment: I added some more details

Comment: There you go. Now you've got everything I think.

Comment: Could you try reading using QDataStream on the socket instead?

Comment: QDataStream doesn't do jack, but the link I checked to see how it's used did.

Well, that and @G.M.'s answer above which I read just after the link.
I feel so silly for making such a stupid mistake.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium QDataStream does solve your problem indeed if correctly used with `startTransaction()` and `commitTransaction()`

Answer (score 0):

You should not invoke send three times but only once. For conversion into BigEndian you might use the [Qt functions](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtendian.html#qToBigEndian) and write everything into a single buffer and only call send once. It is not what you want, but I assume it is what you'll need to do and it should be easy, as you already know the size of you message. You also will not need to leave the Qt world for sending the messages.

Comment: My apologies, I should probably have mentioned, that the sending side is not using Qt at all, since the code needs to work for an embedded system.